# Docker-compose to K8s: How to troubleshoot "Didn't match Pod's node affinity"?

Tags: docker-compose, kubernetes-pod

This is a continuation of the question I asked at [Hyperledger Fabric - migration from Docker swarm to Kubernetes possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66982235/hyperledger-fabric-migration-from-docker-swarm-to-kubernetes-possible)

After I have run `kompose convert` on my docker-compose files, I obtain the files exactly as listed in the answer I accepted. Then I run the following commands in order:

```
$ kubectl apply -f dev-orderer1-pod.yaml
$ kubectl apply -f dev-orderer1-service.yaml
$ kubectl apply -f dev-peer1-pod.yaml
$ kubectl apply -f dev-peer1-service.yaml
$ kubectl apply -f dev-couchdb1-pod.yaml
$ kubectl apply -f dev-couchdb1-service.yaml
$ kubectl apply -f ar2bc-networkpolicy.yaml
```

When I try to view my pods I see this:

```
$ kubectl get pod
NAME           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
dev-couchdb1   0/1     Pending   0          7m20s
dev-orderer1   0/1     Pending   0          8m25s
dev-peer1      0/1     Pending   0          7m39s
```

When I try to describe any of the three pods I see this:

```
$ kubectl describe pod dev-orderer1
Name:         dev-orderer1
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         <none>
Labels:       io.kompose.network/ar2bc=true
              io.kompose.service=dev-orderer1
Annotations:  kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose-orderer1.yaml -f docker-compose-peer1.yaml --volumes hostPath
              kompose.version: 1.22.0 (955b78124)
Status:       Pending
IP:
IPs:          <none>
Containers:
  dev-orderer1:
    Image:      hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest
    Port:       7050/TCP
    Host Port:  0/TCP
    Args:
      orderer
    Environment:
      ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE:  /var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY:   /var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS:            [/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE:                /var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD:              file
      ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS:              0.0.0.0
      ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR:                /var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID:                 OrdererMSP
      ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL:                   INFO
      ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE:            /var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED:                true
      ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY:             /var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS:                [/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
    Mounts:
      /var/hyperledger/orderer/msp from dev-orderer1-hostpath1 (rw)
      /var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block from dev-orderer1-hostpath0 (rw)
      /var/hyperledger/orderer/tls from dev-orderer1-hostpath2 (rw)
      /var/hyperledger/production/orderer from orderer1 (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-44lfq (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  PodScheduled   False
Volumes:
  dev-orderer1-hostpath0:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /home/isprintsg/hlf/channel-artifacts/genesis.block
    HostPathType:
  dev-orderer1-hostpath1:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /home/isprintsg/hlf/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/ar2dev.accessreal.com/orderers/orderer1.ar2dev.accessreal.com/msp
    HostPathType:
  dev-orderer1-hostpath2:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /home/isprintsg/hlf/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/ar2dev.accessreal.com/orderers/orderer1.ar2dev.accessreal.com/tls
    HostPathType:
  orderer1:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /home/isprintsg/hlf
    HostPathType:
  default-token-44lfq:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-44lfq
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  kubernetes.io/hostname=isprintdev
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                 From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  51s (x27 over 27m)  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity.
```

The error message right at the end is common to all three pods. I try to Google that message but surprisingly I don't get any straightforward results. What does that message mean, and how should I go about resolving this? I'm quite new to Kubernetes, in case you're wondering.

---

EDIT

- dev-orderer1-pod.yaml - https://pastebin.com/PQUnz3Q2
- dev-orderer1-service.yaml - https://pastebin.com/gxuHNvAX
- dev-peer1-pod.yaml - https://pastebin.com/hwUQdq5L
- dev-peer1-service.yaml - https://pastebin.com/n2Q8uMFB
- dev-couchdb1-pod.yaml - https://pastebin.com/HTC3TQPz
- dev-couchdb1-service.yaml - https://pastebin.com/Sg6ZkrHz
- ar2bc-networkpolicy.yaml - https://pastebin.com/fjEdAGJe

Comment: "Something in the Pod YAML said this Pod can only run on specific Nodes, but there aren't any Nodes that match that rule."  Seeing the Kubernetes YAML would be useful here.  (The `kubectl describe` also output suggests some `hostPath:` type volumes, which aren't going to be a reliable way to store data, so you'll need to edit these out as well. SO questions have generally suggested to me that Kompose can be a starting point for producing Kubernetes YAML but doesn't really produce a runnable set of artifacts without hand-editing.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I will pastebin the yaml and update my question shortly

Answer (score 5):

I stumbled across this while researching a parallel problem.. in case it helps, I'd imagine that this is your problem:

```
Node-Selectors:  kubernetes.io/hostname=isprintdev
```

The node selector tells Kubernetes to only schedule these pods on a node whose hostname is `isprintdev` :)

D